# Referencing Jars from a MANIFEST file using relative path

Tags: java, jar, classpath, manifest

In Java, I cannot remember referencing jars in a specific way apart from specifying that with path names in the MANIFEST file. I am having issues with `someother.jar` file in the path specified.

`Class-Path: . ../lib/one.jar ../webapps/ROOT/lib/someother.jar`

I can see everything upto `one.jar`. I am hoping this is not some silly line-ending or trailing space issue. But it looks like my protectionDomain comes as
my jar's absolute path location including the jar extension.

I have turned on `-verbose` to check class loading details but I guess without understanding this dotted classpath reference I cannot go further. ANy help is appreciated. :)

my dir structure (apologies for this crud representation):

```
bin
conf
+lib
-tomcat-coyote.jar
-tomcat-juli.jar
-blablabla.jar
tmp
+webapps
--+ROOT
----+lib
------+someother.jar
------+pages
----+classes
```

Comment: This looks like you're using a webserver or application server and `someother.jar` is located in a web application's lib folder. If that's true that your other application can't see that by design: web applications are isolated, i.e. their classes and libraries should not be accessible from the outside.

Comment: @Thomas         okay I understand, but how did I manage to see `one.jar` ? which is technically the same way going one level up. I am not saying your answer is incorrect, I am just a little confused about this rule.

Comment: Well, `../lib/` indicates a folder of shared libraries, i.e. ones that all applications within the webserver should have access to. The issue is not the length of the path etc. but the enclosing artifacts: `one.jar` has none (i.e. it seems to be on server level) while `someother.jar` is part of the `ROOT` web application and thus isolation rules apply. However, since there's a lot of information missing I can only guess so take this with some grain of salt :)

Comment: Many servers use `lib` as a special directory whose .jar files are placed in the classpath of every deployed application.  I’m guessing this is why you can see one.jar, and the ../lib/one.jar in your Class-Path attribute is actually being ignored.

Comment: @VGR           actually, I can confirm that it's not the case, even when I have got it in the classpath, my custom jar cannot see it unless I have added it as part of my manifest. I believe @Thomas@ has probably made a valid point where certain restrictions are applied to application-specific `lib` directories